# Parsing ES6 Class Objects From localStorage Doesn't Include Class Functions

Tags: javascript, class, local-storage, persistence

I want to persist a class object in HTML5 localStorage.  The class contains methods which I also need to persist, but parsing the localStorage object reveals that the object isn't the same.

```
class ExcitingMath {

    constructor(firstNumber, secondNumber) {

        this._firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this._secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }

    add() {

        return this._firstNumber + this._secondNumber;
    }

    subtract() {

        return this._firstNumber - this._secondNumber;
    }
}

const eMath = new ExcitingMath(2, 4);
```

Logging `eMath` in the console displays the class object with it's properties and methods:

[image]

However, when I `localStorage.setItem("math", JSON.stringify(eMath));` and `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("math"));` the object to and from `localStorage`, it no longer includes the constructor or methods.

[image]

How can I persist the original class instance with localStorage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible since JSON.toString just saves the STATE of the object, but not the object's functions as you have already found out. I faced the same "problem" and wrote a function "fromJSON" in my classes which takes the JSON from localstorage and transforms that into an object as follows:

```
class ExcitingMath {

    constructor(firstNumber, secondNumber) {

        this._firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this._secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }

    add() {

        return this._firstNumber + this._secondNumber;
    }

    subtract() {

        return this._firstNumber - this._secondNumber;
    }

    static fromJSON(serializedJson) {
        return Object.assign(new ExcitingMath(), JSON.parse(serializedJson))
    }
}
```

You then may use it as follows:

```
const eMath = ExcitingMath.fromJSON(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("math")))
```

Comment: Given the mehod signature of `static fromJSON(json)` consider just passing the text. Then in the method do something like `return Object.assign(new ExcitingMath(), JSON.parse(text))`. See [*Object.assign*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.assign) for the properties. So it would be `ExcitingMath.fromJSON(text)` . ;-).

Comment: I believe your example needs to be updated to drop the `JSON.parse()`. With your last edit to account for the comment above it looks like you're doing a parse twice now.